# How to pass the result of a select to another select?

Tags: sql, postgresql

`select dates from mytable order by dates`.

```
2016-01-01
2016-01-03
2016-01-07
...
```

How can I pass those parameters one by one to another select? I want/have to pass those parameters one by one!

Something like:

`select * from mytable2 where <someconditions> and somedate = <passed param prom previous select>`

Is that ever possible?
The `dates` select should only be running once, and the result should be reused by passing each value one by one as argument.

Comment: `JOIN`, `IN`, or `EXISTS`, come to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Select *
    From mytable2
   Where <someconditions>
     And date In (Select date from mytable)
Order By date
```